# Can we insert three images using three input type file in a single php form?

Tags: php, file, input, upload

since i'm a newbie in PHP i'm asking this question. I can do a single insert image with a nice validation but i want to do this with 3 image. (leave the validation part). Just correct me if i'm wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Can i insert three images with the following format? It takes 7 days to ask next question, please help me out guys.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['upload'])) 
{
$fileName1  = $_FILES["uploaded_one"]["name"]; 
$fileTmp1   = $_FILES["uploaded_one"]["tmp_name"]; 
$fileType1  = $_FILES["uploaded_one"]["type"]; 
$fileSize1  = $_FILES["uploaded_one"]["size"];  

$fileName2  = $_FILES["uploaded_two"]["name"]; 
$fileTmp2   = $_FILES["uploaded_two"]["tmp_name"]; 
$fileType2  = $_FILES["uploaded_two"]["type"]; 
$fileSize2  = $_FILES["uploaded_two"]["size"]; 

$fileName3  = $_FILES["uploaded_three"]["name"]; 
$fileTmp3   = $_FILES["uploaded_three"]["tmp_name"]; 
$fileType3  = $_FILES["uploaded_three"]["type"]; 
$fileSize3  = $_FILES["uploaded_three"]["size"]; 

if (!preg_match("/.(jpeg|jpg|png)$/i", $fileName1 || $fileName2 || $fileName3) )

$folder = "upload/";
$moveResult1 = move_uploaded_file($fileTmp1, "$folder/$fileName1");
$moveResult2 = move_uploaded_file($fileTmp2, "$folder/$fileName2");
$moveResult3 = move_uploaded_file($fileTmp3, "$folder/$fileName3");



$insert   = "SQL INSERT QUERY TIRED TO TYPE";
$run = mysqli_query($db,$insert);
}
?>        
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="uploaded_one" />
<input type="file" name="uploaded_two" />
<input type="file" name="uploaded_three" />  
<button name="upload">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And I think my preg_match() is giving error. is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why would it not work? Did you try it? What you showed looks ok, although you might want arrays instead of variables with suffix `1`, `2`, `3`. There could be an error in your SQL query, and you haven't actually called [`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) on the files you get in the POST request, nor do any error checking.

Comment: How about now a little update. and can you help me with array stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array with the name suffix and loop through the array while you check each file separately.

```
foreach(['one', 'two', 'three'] as $item)
    $name  = $_FILES["uploaded_{$item}"]["name"];
    $tmp   = $_FILES["uploaded_{$item}"]["tmp_name"];
    $type  = $_FILES["uploaded_{$item}"]["type"];
    $size  = $_FILES["uploaded_{$item}"]["size"];

    if (!preg_match("/.(jpeg|jpg|png)$/i", $name))
        $folder = "upload/";
    $result = move_uploaded_file($tmp, "$folder/$name");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use just an input multiple for upload your 3 files un the same input ?

Comment: since the file would be used for different purpose, instead of stacking them together, i thought the above would be best for that.

Comment: Ok. Get the files with and post theme to the PHP with Ajax.